# Why isn't Kafka consumer producing results?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

As a Kafka learning exercise, I have written a Java program `TsdbMetricToKafkaTopic` to copy data from openTSDB to a Kafka topic, and another Java program `DumpKafkaTopic` to print out the results; below is the key method of `DumpKafkaTopic`.

I have confirmed, by using the Kafka utility `kafka-console-consumer.sh`, that the data I expect are indeed getting written to the intended topic.  *However*, the behavior of `DumpKafkaTopic` is strange:   When I run the producer and then `DumpKafkaTopic`, it prints results as I'd expect.  However, if I re-run it immediately, it prints nothing.

I *thought* that because I set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`, my program would be idempotent, that is, every time I run it, it should produce the same results (until I write something else to the topic).  Why isn't this happening?

```
public void dump( String kafka_topic ) {

    // Serializers/deserializers (serde) for key and value types
    final Serde<Long> long_serde = Serdes.Long();
    final Serde< TsdbObject > tsdb_object_serde = 
        Serdes.serdeFrom( new TsdbObject.TsdbObjectSerializer(), 
                          new TsdbObject.TsdbObjectDeserializer() );

    StreamsBuilder streams_builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream< Long, TsdbObject > kstream = 
        streams_builder.stream( kafka_topic, Consumed.with( long_serde, tsdb_object_serde ) );

    // Add final operator, to print results to stdout:
    Printed< Long, TsdbObject > printed = Printed.toSysOut();
    kstream.print( printed );

    Map<String, Object> kstreams_props = new HashMap<>();
    kstreams_props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "DumpKafkaTopic");
    kstreams_props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

    // make sure to consume the complete topic via "auto.offset.reset = earliest"
    kstreams_props.put( ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    StreamsConfig kstreams_config = new StreamsConfig(kstreams_props);

    KafkaStreams kstreams = new KafkaStreams( streams_builder.build(), kstreams_config );
    System.out.println( "Starting DumpKafkaTopic stream " );

    kstreams.start();

    // Add shutdown hook to respond to SIGTERM and gracefully close Kafka Streams (from https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/)
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println( "Stopping DumpKafkaTopic stream " );
                kstreams.close();
            }
        }));                
}
```

Comment: Sorry, title is not accurate.   What I meant is that the log messages from Kafka indicate that, despite my code, it's still using the ByteArray[] deserializer for my topic values, and I'm wondering if that's why I'm not seeing anything coming out of the print() operation.

Comment: I've seen this too. I think there's a timeout where Kafka waits for your app to commit the offsets before resetting (or something). If you also set GROUP_ID_CONFIG to a UUID you will get the behaviour you want.

Comment: I tried adding a setting of GROUP_ID_CONFIG as you suggested:

        // make sure to consume the complete topic via "auto.offset.reset = earliest"
        kstreams_props.put( ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        kstreams_props.put( ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID() );

but it didn't seem to make any difference:   I still need to rerun the producer program in order to get the consumer program to say anything.