# How can I reset Kafka state to "start of universe"?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm still working on a Kafka Streams application that I described in 
[Why isn't Kafka consumer producing results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564468/why-isnt-kafka-consumer-producing-results?noredirect=1#comment86164434_49564468).  In that posting, I asked why setting

```
kstreams_props.put( ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

doesn't appear to reset the state of Kafka to "start of the universe" before any data are pushed to any topic.  I am now encountering a variant of that issue:

My application consists of a producer program that pushes data to a Kafka stream and a consumer program that groups the data, aggregates the groups, and then converts the resulting KTable back into a stream, which I print out.

The aggregation step is essentially adding up all the values, then putting those sums into the output stream as new data.  What I observe, though, is that every time I run the program, the resulting aggregated values get bigger and bigger, almost as if Kafka is somehow retaining the previous results and including those in the aggregation.

In order to try fixing this, I deleted *all* my topics (except for `__consumer_offsets`, which Kafka would not allow), then re-ran my application, but the aggregated values continue to grow, as if Kafka were retaining the result of previous computations even though I *thought* that deleting the intermediate topics would fix things.  I even tried stopping and restarting the Kafka server, to no avail.

What's going on here and, more to the point, how can I fix this?   I've tried various suggestions about setting `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG`, also with no effect.  I should mention that one aspect of my application is that my original producer creates its own Kafka timestamps in the `Producer.send` call, although disabling that also seemed to have no effect.

Thanks in advance,  -- Mark

Answer (score 2):

`AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` only triggers if there are not committed offsets: If an application starts, it first looks for committed offsets and applies the reset policy only, if there are no valid offsets.

Furthermore, for a Kafka Streams application, resetting offsets would not be sufficient and you should use the reset tool `bin/kafka-streams-applicaion-reset.sh` -- this blog post explains the tool in details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/